# Row merging ActiveReports issues

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, activereports

I have a problem when working with table in activereports 7.please show me way to merge 2 rows into single row.it likes rowspan attribute in html
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option would be to make use of the [Matrix](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/Matrix.html) dataregion than the Table control.
When using the Matrix Dataregion, the cells with same values are merged automatically. You may refer to the [documentation](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/CellMergingInMatrix.html) for further clarification and implementation.

Regards,
Mohita

Comment: Thank for your help!
In the Matrix data region, cells with same values are merged automatically to delete duplicate values.But i wanna fix the number of rows when merging.I need design by a given template.have you other solution?
Thank you!

Comment: As of now, you cannot fix the number rows for merging in matrix. However, what exactly is the user scenario for implementing this? This might help us in providing you with other solution.